# Random sized javascript canvas rectangles

Tags: javascript, canvas, random, size, rectangles

I'm trying to randomly size rectangles, drawn in the canvas, using javascript.

But it doesn't show anything on the screen.

```
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

            var contx = canv.getContext("2d");

            contx.beginPath();
            contx.lineWidth = "100";
            contx.strokeStyle = "#DEDEDE";
            contx.rect(910, 400, Math.floor((Math.random()*150)+150), Math.floor((Math.random()*150)+150));
            contx.stroke();
```

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Comment: This problem couldve been solved faster using the browser debugger tools (`F12` in most cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have a typo:** canv.getContext("2d") **should be** `canvas.getContext("2d")`

Comment: Thanks a lot, haven't seen that! ^_^